# connecting points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot

```
require(ggplot2)

dtf <- structure(list(Variance = c(5.213, 1.377, 0.858, 0.613, 0.412, 0.229, 0.139, 0.094, 0.064), Component = structure(1:9, .Label = c("PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4", "PC5", "PC6", "PC7", "PC8", "PC9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Variance", "Component"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dtf, aes(x = Component, y = Variance)) +
geom_point()
```

[image]

I would simply like to connect the dots with straight lines. I tried `+geom_line()` but that generated an error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `x` values are discrete (factor) and `geom_line()` each unique `x` value perceive as separate group and tries to connect points only inside this group. Setting `group=1` in `aes()` ensures that all values are treated as one group.

```
ggplot(dtf, aes(x = Component, y = Variance,group=1)) +
  geom_point()+geom_line()
```

Comment: (+1) probably you should explain why this has happened.

Comment: +1 nice,  thanks. It would have taken me ages to work that out !

Comment: If you're using an additional aesthetic to compare data from different conditions on the same axes with something like `x=Throttle, y=Acceleration, color=Widget` you can add `group=Widget` to draw lines connecting points from the same widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This would plot the points with x as the integer values of the factor categories:

```
 ggplot(dtf, aes(x = as.numeric(Component), y = Variance)) +
      geom_point() + geom_line()
```

You can put back in the category labels with:

```
ggplot(dtf, aes(x = as.numeric(Component), y = Variance)) +
  geom_point() +geom_line() + scale_x_discrete(labels=dtf$Component)
```

Comment: Thanks. The main problem with this is that it also requires changing the x axis label to avoid it saying "as.numeric(Component)"

Comment: Agree. It was certainly not optimal. Requires 2 fixes and I've so far only applied one. You should accept the other answer.