# ggplot2: geom_line() for single observations (x-factor, y-numeric)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and simple code

```
library(ggplot2)
dane <- data.frame(mylevels=c(1,2,5,9), myvalues=c(2, 5, 3, 4))
ggplot(dane, aes(x=factor(mylevels), y=myvalues)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=3)
```

I'm not able to figure out how to force "ggplot2" to draw the line - I get an error. On pp. 55 (R Graphics Cookbook) Winston Chang describes the same error but my plot is simpler that's why his solution can't be adopted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [connecting points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043956/connecting-points)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should add `group=1` inside `aes()` to connect points with line.

```
ggplot(dane, aes(x=factor(mylevels), y=myvalues,group=1)) + 
       geom_line() + geom_point(size=3)
```