# geom_line() not working in ggplot using grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to compare the average number of reviews an android app receives based on the month it was last updated. Here is my code / geom_point graph:

```
# Creating a group-means data set
gd <- appset %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(Reviews=mean(Reviews))

ggplot(appset, aes(Month, log(Reviews))) +
geom_point(data=gd) + scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)
```

[Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIP56.jpg)

My problem: I have been able to create a scatterplot, but I would like to connect the dots with geom_line() or geom_path(), but instead I keep getting the same scatterplot with vertical lines drawing up from the x-axis through each point. Here's my code and and image:

```
ggplot(appset, aes(Month, log(Reviews))) +
geom_point(data=gd) + geom_line() +
scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)
```

[Attempted with geom_line()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zG1I.jpg)

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043956/connecting-points

Comment: Hi! thanks! I think my question is pretty clear, and unfortunately the other suggested post does not apply, nor do the answers solve my dilemma. I am working with grouped data, and I think this is where the problem stems from

Comment: Without a reproducible example (including sample data) it's hard to answer your question. One thing to try is to change your code to read `geom_line(data=gd)`, as otherwise the data is inherited from the original ggplot call (in addition to adding `group=1` to the ggplot call as suggested in the duplicate question referred to above).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're passing appset as the main data if all your points are taken from gd?

Comment: Hi iod, Thanks for actually answering my question! No reason, other than that I'm a beginner. I passed gd as the main data and it worked! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. However, zx8754 is right in asking that you provide a reproducible example. Much easier for everyone -- plus, in trying to create a reproducible example, you'll find you'll often find the problem by yourself, so it's a good exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

```
ggplot(appset, aes(Month, log(Reviews))) +
geom_point(data=gd) + geom_line(data=gd) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)
```

You need to add `data=gd` to the `geom_line` call, otherwise the data is inherited from the original ggplot call.